# Counting objects in folders in a bucket

Tags: powershell, gsutil

Trying to count objects inside every folder inside the bucket (1 layer only)

Here is what i tried:

```
chcp 65001
Foreach($v in gsutil ls "gs://bucket/*"){
    echo $v (gsutil ls $v).Length
}
```

It works fine at first, but there are 2 cases that cause errors:

1. Folders containing "#" sign would cause the error "One or more URLs matched no objects."
2. Folders containing Chinese Characters (i tried Chinese only) would have encoding issues, causing `$v` incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need regex. I have never used [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.1) but the principle is the same. You can match Chinese characters with regex like this:

[Documentation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#script)

```
\p{script=Han}

or

\p{Han}
```

To match only a `#` you can do this:

```
(\#)
```